# Error when running grunt on my OAuth Daemon instance

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, coffeescript, gruntjs

I've installed OAuthD (http://www.evereq.io/evereq/DE), a background API server,  on a virtual machine running a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 x32. I followed these directions listed in the quickstart section of the documentation (https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/wiki/Quickstart) and I'm able to successfully create an oauthd instance using 'oauthd init'. But once I enter the directory of the instance and run 'sudo npm install && sudo grunt', I get the following error:

```
oauthdgui@oauthdgui-VirtualBox:~/vjf$ sudo npm install && sudo grunt
>> No "coffee" targets found.
Warning: Task "coffee" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The newest version of Grunt is being used, along with the newest version of nodejs and redis. I'm pretty inexperienced with Ubuntu and setting up a server such as this, feel free to make any helpful suggestions. Also I've already tried "--force".

```
oauthdgui@oauthdgui-VirtualBox:~/vjf$ sudo grunt --force
[sudo] password for oauthdgui: 
>> No "coffee" targets found.
Warning: Task "coffee" failed. Used --force, continuing.
>> No "subgrunt" targets found.
Warning: Task "subgrunt" failed. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```